# How to use memory allocation to store values in an array using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've written a code with a main body plus a function `merge()` that merges two arrays `arr1[]` and `arr2[]` and stores them in a third array, `*arr3[]`.

I'm still confused by the pointers and memory allocation. What sort of command should I place in my code to tell it to put the two merged arrays into a third array, `*arr3[]`?

I tried writing `*arr3 = (double *) malloc (*sz3)` but I received an error "ld returned 1 exit status".

Here is the code:

```c
/* This is a function that will merge contents of arr1 and arr2 and store in  arr3 as a 
   pointer */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void merge(double arr1[], double arr2[], double *arr3[], int sz1, int sz2, int *sz3);  
void print_arr(double arr[], int sz);

int main(){
    double v0[] = {};
    double v1[] = {22.0, 30.1, 35.2, 49.2, 56.4, 65.1, 76.4, 79.6, 86.2, 88.9};
    double v2[] = {4.6, 9.0, 13.0, 47.8, 66.9, 68.7, 71.0};
    double v3[] = {80.1, 92.7, 97.4, 102.3, 105.0, 112.3, 121, 136.7, 163.4, 177.9};
    int sz1 = 10, sz2 = 7, sz3 = 10, szres;
    double *res;

    printf("\nTEST 1\n======\n");
    merge(v1, v2, &res, sz1, sz2, &szres);
    print_arr(res,szres);
    free(res);

    printf("\nTEST 2\n======\n");
    merge(v0, v3, &res, 0, sz3, &szres);
    print_arr(res,szres);
    free(res);

    printf("\nTEST 3\n======\n");
    merge(v2, v3, &res, sz2, sz3, &szres);
    print_arr(res,szres);
    free(res);

    return 0;
}

/* function to print the array */
void print_arr(double arr[], int sz){
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        printf("%7.2lf",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void merge(double arr1[], double arr2[], double *arr3[], int sz1, int sz2, int *sz3) {

    int i, j, k;
    j = k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < (sz1+sz2);) {    
        if(j < sz1 && k < sz2) {
            if (arr1[j] < arr2[k]) {
                *arr3[i] = arr1[j];
                j++;
            } else {
                *arr3[i] = arr2[k];
                k++;
            }    
            i++;
        } else if (j == sz1) {
            for (; i < (sz1 + sz2);) {
                *arr3[i] = arr2[k];
                k++;
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            for (; i < (sz1+sz2);) {
                *arr3[i] = arr1[j];
                j++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ld is your linker. That means you're probably trying to use a symbol that doesn't exist. The linker told you what the problem was, but you didn't include the full error message here.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it, however, I still can't get the merged array to be stored in arr3[].

Comment: Please also add your `malloc` statement to the code.

Comment: You should take all the error messages your compiler throws at you with great consideration. Use the `-Wall `and `-Wextra` compiler command-line options.

Comment: `*arr3[]` is an array of pointers to double values. This means that a simple `memcpy()` won't work because you don't want to copy the values of `arr1[]` and `arr2[]` into the addresses in `*arr3[]`. Instead you'll have to iterate through the arrays and copy each element to the value pointed to by each pointer in `*arr3[]` one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

The function parameter `double *arr3[]` is an array of `double *`.  You're instead passing in a pointer to a `double *`, so you need to define it as `double **arr3`:

```
void merge(double arr1[], double arr2[], double **arr3, int sz1, int sz2, int *sz3) {
```

To properly allocate the right amount of memory, you need to first assign a value to `*sz3`.  Then you can allocate space for that many doubles.

Right before the initial `for` loop in `merge`, add the following:

```
*sz3 = sz1+sz2;
*arr3 = malloc((*sz3) * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful feedback!

Comment: @A.JosephDesmond Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.